# How to query a nested object with combined AND and OR logic?

Tags: elasticsearch

How should this expression be written as a query:

*(attributes.id = 14 OR attributes.id = 15) AND (attributes.id = 4843 OR attributes.id = 4859)*

The nested object looks like this:

```
{  
  "attributes":[  
    {  
      "id":14,
      "type":"color",
      "name":"Sort",
      "version":1
    },
    {  
      "id":15,
      "type":"color",
      "name":"Sølv",
      "version":1
    },
    {  
      "id":2031,
      "type":"brand",
      "name":"Jimmy Choo",
      "version":1
    },
    {  
      "id":4843,
      "type":"size",
      "name":"36x28",
      "version":1
    },
    {  
      "id":4859,
      "type":"size",
      "name":"38x36",
      "version":1
    },
    {  
      "id":4927,
      "type":"size",
      "name":"60J",
      "version":1
    },
    {  
      "id":4958,
      "type":"size",
      "name":"75F",
      "version":1
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried using this query - among many - without any luck:

```
{  
  "query":{  
    "nested":{  
      "path":"attributes",
      "query":{  
        "bool":{  
          "should":[  
            {  
              "terms":{  
                "attributes.id":[  
                  14,
                  15
                ]
              }
            },
            {  
              "terms":{  
                "attributes.id":[  
                  4843,
                  4859
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match":2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query returns zero results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on [Elastic Stack by Daniel_Penning](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-query-a-nested-object-with-combined-and-and-or-logic/102805/5):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "variants.attributes",
            "query": {
              "terms": {
                "variants.attributes.id": [
                  14, 15
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "variants.attributes",
            "query": {
              "terms": {
                "variants.attributes.id": [
                  4843, 4859
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{  
  "query":{  
   "nested":{  
  "path":"attributes",
  "query":{  
    "bool":{  
      "must":[{
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                   "term": {
                      "attributes.id": 14
                   }
               },{
                   "term": {
                      "attributes.id": 15
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
      },{
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                   "term": {
                      "attributes.id": 4843
                   }
               },{
                   "term": {
                      "attributes.id": 4859
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
      }
      ]
  }
}
```

}

This should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately, it doesn't work. No hits returned.
I'm using Elasticsearch 5.6.2 if it makes any difference.